# How to update reactive Objects (and properties in general)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue.js documentation on [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) mentions that

> a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to
> convert it and make it reactive

(...)

> you have to initialize Vue instances by declaring all root-level
> reactive data properties upfront, even just with an empty value

Consider these two code snippets, where `tags` is defined as an empty object and updated in the course of the script, in two different ways:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    tags: {}
  }
});

vm.tags = {
  hello: true,
  world: true
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  {{tags}}
</div>
```

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    tags: {}
  }
});

vm.tags["hello"] = true
vm.tags["world"] = true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  {{tags}}
</div>
```

In the first case, the content is correctly updated, and in the second - not.

**Why is it so, despite the fact that in both cases `tags` were declared at the VM instantiation?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that the `tags` object is declared, it's that the properties on the `tags` object do not exist when the Vue is instantiated.

In the second case you are adding two new properties to the `tags` object by using an indexer. Vue *cannot* detect that those properties were added.

This is why the [`$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) method exists. When you add a new property to an object, you need to add it via `$set` or `Vue.set`

```
 Vue.set(vm.tags, 'hello', true)
```

or, if you are inside a Vue method,

```
this.$set(this.tags, 'hello', true)
```

In the *first* case, you are adding a completely different object that *has* the properties. That being the case, Vue is aware of the properties and converts them into *reactive* properties when the new value is added to data.

If *instead* you added a new empty object and *then* added the properties, you would be back in the same case as your second example.

Typically, you just want to initialize the object with the empty properties.

```
data: {
    tags:{
        hello: false,
        world: false
    }
}
```

In which case, the properties will be converted to reactive properties and changes will be detected.

**Edit**

@WoJ posted a comment with a pen with code that looks like this:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    posts: {},
    tags: {}
  }
});

vm.tags = {
  hello: true,
  world: true
};

vm.posts["bonjour"] = true
vm.posts["monde"] = true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <!-- show all tags which are on -->
  {{tags}}
  {{posts}}
</div>
```

In this code it *appears* that the `posts` property of the Vue is updated with new reactive properties because they are displayed in the output when the Vue is rendered. What is happening here is that the properties *are* added to the `posts` object, that's just how javascript works, you can add properties to objects, but *Vue* doesn't *know* they are there. More specifically, these properties are not added as *reactive* properties (getters/setters) which is how Vue knows when changes occur to data that has been added to the Vue. In fact, adding these properties to the `posts` object **does not trigger a render**.

So, why do the new properties show up in the output? The reason the new `posts` properties show up in the output is because setting the `tags` property to a new object triggers a render to be scheduled. **It's important to know that Vue renders are *not* synchronous, they are asynchronous** (see [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue)).

> ... Vue performs DOM updates
> asynchronously. Whenever a data change is observed, it will open a
> queue and buffer all the data changes that happen in the same event
> loop.
>
> For example, when you set vm.someData = 'new value', the component
> will not re-render immediately. It will update in the next “tick”,
> when the queue is flushed.

In the code example above, the update to `tags` triggers a render to be scheduled. Then, the `posts` object is updated with two new properties that are *not* converted to reactive properties because Vue doesn't know they exist. *Then* some time later, the scheduled render occurs and Vue updates the HTML with the *current* state of the objects in data. Since `posts` *does* have those two new properties, those properties are rendered to the screen. Updates to those properties, however, will *never* trigger an update to render.

To see this is the case, simply comment out the update to the `tags` property.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    posts: {},
    tags: {}
  }
});

//vm.tags = {
//  hello: true,
//  world: true
//};

vm.posts["bonjour"] = true
vm.posts["monde"] = true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <!-- show all tags which are on -->
  {{tags}}
  {{posts}}
</div>
```

Notice, in this case, the rendered Vue *never* changes.

Comment: Thanks, I spent so many hours trying to debug this - also because CodePen behaves differently. https://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/bRGamg for instance shows both of my examples are working...

Comment: @WoJ It doesn't really behave differently in your pen, it just *looks* like it does. If you log vm.posts and vm.tags after you make changes in your pen, you will see that vm.posts is *not* reactive (they are not observed). If you comment out the update to vm.tags, you will see that no change is ever rendered on screen. This is because the change to vm.tags causes a render to be scheduled and when that render occurs, both properties are shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed description of the CodePen case, specifically pointing at the asynchronous nature of the rendering following a trigger. This is very clear now. It is a shame I cannot double-upvote :)

Comment: @WoJ glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because in the first case, you are running a *setter* on `tags` (because you are reassigning it) - which Vue has wrapped and can detect. In the second case, you're running setters on nested properties that were *not* in your `data: { tags: {` definition, so they are not reactive.

The [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) section in the documentation covers this, though not *exactly* the same as your case (the nested properties situation). You would have to declare your data like:

```
data: {
  tags: {
    hello: null,
    world: null,
  }
}
```