# Vuetify v-data-table not showing results from javascript api fetch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am a beginner with javascript and vue/vuetify.

I have a v-data-table which I can populate with static results. However I want to populate it on a click -> flask api call.

I have:

index.html

```
 <v-data-table
        :headers = "headers"
        :items="citylist"
        :items-per-page="10"
        caption = "City List"
        class="elevation-1"
        fixed
        style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: auto"
      >
      </v-data-table>
```

main.js

```
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   vuetify: new Vuetify(),
   data() {
        return {
        headers: [
            {
              text: 'cityname',
              align: 'left',
              sortable: 'false',
              value: "cityname"
              },
            { text: "index", value: "index" }
            ],
        citylist: [],
```

.....................................

```
   methods: {
        get_data(sortorder) {
            const self = this
            const url = `api/citylist?order=${sortorder}`
            fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => self.citylist = json['citylist'])
            }
  }
```

})

My method is obviously not right! Any ideas on updating citylist correctly?!

Just updating. The json now looks like this:

```
     {
  "citylist": [
    {
      "cityname": "Valletta", 
      "index": 13
    }, 
    {
      "cityname": "Lisbon", 
      "index": 11
    }, 
    {
      "cityname": "Nicosia", 
      "index": 11
    }, 
    {
      "cityname": "Athens", 
      "index": 10
    }
```

Comment: what does the JSON look like

Comment: Thanks for looking. This is what is showing in the console log:
(47) […]
​
0: {…}
​​
Valletta: 13
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
1: {…}
​​
Lisbon: 11
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
2: {…}
​​
Nicosia: 11
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
3: Object { Athens: 10 }
​
4: Object { Monaco: 10 }
​
5: Object { Rome: 8 }

Comment: I wonder it this is also a problem?! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345964/how-to-update-reactive-objects-and-properties-in-general

Comment: Based on the code you've written, your JSON should be formatted like this: `{ "citylist" : [ { "cityname": "Valletta", "index": 13},  { "cityname": "Lisbon", "index": 11}, ... ] }` The method that sets citylist is fine, it's the format of the JSON that is throwing you off.

Comment: Yeeha! Thanks so much. Updated and now we are go! That's great! Hmmmm can you repost your answer into an answer? I am new to this but can't see how to vote you up!

Comment: No problem! I just responded with the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've written, your JSON should be formatted like this:

```
{
  "citylist": [
    {
      "cityname": "Valletta",
      "index": 13
    },
    {
      "cityname": "Valletta",
      "index": 13
    },
    ...
   ]
}
```

The method that sets citylist is fine, it's the format of the JSON that is throwing you off.

Comment: Marvellous. Thanks.